# How to scrape specific columns from table with BeautifulSoup and return as pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Trying to parse the table with HDI and load the data into the Pandas DataFrame with columns: Country, HDI_score.

I'm stuck with loading the Nation column with the following code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_Human_Development_Index")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Countries', 'HDI_score'])
for row in table.find_all('tr'):    
    columns = row.find_all('td')
    
    if(columns != []):
        countries = columns[1].text.strip()
        hdi_score = columns[2].text.strip()
        df = df.append({'Countries': countries, 'HDI_score': hdi_score}, ignore_index=True)
```

[Result from my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onvig.png)

So instead of having names of countries, I have values from column 'Rank changes over 5 years'. I've tried changing the column's index but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use pandas to grab the appropriate table, `match='Rank'` getting you the right table, then extract the columns of interest.

```
import pandas as pd

table = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_Human_Development_Index', match='Rank')[0]
columns = ['Nation','HDI']
table = table.loc[:, columns].iloc[:, :2]
table.columns = columns
print(table)
```

---

As per comments, I see little point involving bs4 if you are still using pandas. See as below:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_Human_Development_Index')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
table = pd.read_html(str(soup.select_one('table:has(th:contains("Rank"))')))[0]
columns = ['Nation','HDI']
table = table.loc[:, columns].iloc[:, :2]
table.columns = columns
print(table)
```

Comment: Thank you for the working solution. Nonetheless, I wonder if it is still solvable with bs..

Comment: Of course it is. Just more effort as you are already using pandas so you will use more code and it will be less efficient. I added an edit to answer.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I really appreciate it 

Answer (score 1):

**Note** *Voted for QHarr because it would also be the most straightforward solution to use `pandas` in my opinion*

---

**In addition** and to answer your question - Selecting columns **via `BeautifulSoup` only** would also be possible. Just combine `css selectors` and `stripped_strings`.

#### Example

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_Human_Development_Index")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

pd.DataFrame(
    [list(r.stripped_strings)[-3:-1] for r in bsObj.select('table tr:has(span[data-sort-value])')],
    columns=['Countries', 'HDI_score']
)
```

#### Output

| Countries | HDI_score |
| --- | --- |
| Norway | 0.957 |
| Ireland | 0.955 |
| Switzerland | 0.955 |
| ... | ... |